# Im building .jar of my program in InteliJ, but I added external .jar with JTatto LookAndFeel and the app doesn't work from desktop. How to repair it?

Tags: jar, look-and-feel

It's simple application. I'm pretty sure it doesn't work now from Desktop, because of external .jar added at the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, basically just go in project settings, dependencies, add your jar (dont export) and then build normally
I had to create new project to make it work